# Syncfusion RichTextEditor ASP.Net MVC Format dropdown

Tags: rich-text-editor, syncfusion

Can someone please help me how can I change the contents of Formats dropdown in richtexteditor ej2 syncfusion?

At the moment, default values are: Paragraph, Code, Quotation, Heading 1 etc.

I want to remove the Code, Quotation and add a new custom Format called "My Paragraph".

I have gone through the documentation and apparently, it is not listed.

Help will be appreciated.
Here is what my current configuration is:

```
@Html.EJS().RichTextEditor("table").ToolbarSettings(e => e.Items((object)ViewBag.tools)).Value((string)ViewBag.value).QuickToolbarSettings(e => { e.Table((object)ViewBag.table); }).InsertImageSettings(new RichTextEditorImageSettings() { Path = "/Uploads/", SaveUrl = "/Home/Save" }).ShowCharCount(true).MaxLength(2000).Created("created").Render()
```

Controller method return configuration in viewbag

```
 var tools = new
        {
            tooltipText = "Custom Tools",
            template = "<button class='e-tbar-btn e-btn' tabindex='-1' id='custom_tbar' style='width:100%'><div class='e-tbar-btn-text rtecustomtool' style='font-weight: 500;'> Custom Tools</div></button>"
        };

        ViewBag.tools = new object[] {
            "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "StrikeThrough",
            "FontColor", "BackgroundColor",
            "LowerCase", "UpperCase", "|",
            "Formats", "Alignments", "OrderedList", "UnorderedList",
            "Outdent", "Indent", "CreateTable","|",
            "CreateLink", "Image", "|", "ClearFormat", "Print",
            "SourceCode", "FullScreen", tools,"|", "Undo", "Redo"
        };

        ViewBag.table = new[] {
            "tableRows","tableColumns","tableCellVerticalAlign","tableCellHorizontalAlign","backgroundcolor"
        };
        ViewBag.value="";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the existing “format” option using **Format** property as shown below.

[View]

```
@Html.EJS().RichTextEditor("default").Format((object)ViewBag.types).ActionBegin("onBegin").Render() 
<script> 
    function onBegin(e) { 
        alert(e.element.textContent + " is Selected"); 
    } 
</script>
```

[Controller]

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
    object format1 = new { text = "Paragraph", value = "P" }; 
    object format2 = new { text = "My Paragraph", value = "BlockQuote" }; 
    object format3 = new { text = "Heading 1", value = "H1" }; 
    object format4 = new { text = "Heading 2", value = "H2" }; 
    ViewBag.types = new { width = "40px", 
        types = new[] { format1, format2, format3, format4 } 
    }; 
    return View(); 
}
```

If the newly added item has any predefined format, you can mention that format in value. Else if you want to perform custom action, then you can get the selected item through actionBegin event of RTE and perform required action there. Now the items will be displayed in toolbar as shown below

[image: Screenshot]

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/141071/ze/RTE_Format-454084643)

Comment: Can you please tell how can I give custom css classes in tag to these new formats? what will be the key for that?

Comment: I have tried "spriteCssClass" and "cssClass" option but none of them worked for me

Comment: @Ahmad Currently we cannot give the CSS Classes through C#. This will be fixed and released in upcoming 2018 Volume 4 release.